# How to get "Bus Service No" using google api

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a latitude and longitude of two places. I can get the direction to reach the destination by below api with mode=transit.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=place_id:ChIJVwkdVbQTrjsRGUkefteUeFk&destination=place_id:ChIJIZo0S_EUrjsR_yPLFVLgvHw&mode=transit&key=YOUR_API_KEY

But it don't return the "Bus Service No" as it is shown in google map. 
[Google map with bus service no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfqKi.png)

Can we get all the buses between the specified location using google api or any api

Comment: hi did you got the solution to the above problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the documentation of [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Introduction) using the parameter `mode=transit` or `transit_mode=bus`, they did not specify the service number of vehicles that will be used in the transit mode.

If you check the [Transit Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsResponseElements) of the documentation, it contains the following field line that contains information about the transit line used in this step, and may include the following properties:

- `name` contains the full name of this transit line. eg. **"7 Avenue Express"**.
- `color` contains the color commonly used in signage for this transit line. The color will be specified as a hex string such as: **#FF0033**.
- `agencies` contains an array of `TransitAgency` objects that each provide information about the operator of the line.
- `short_name` contains the short name of this transit line. This will normally be a line number, such as **"M7"** or **"355"**.
- `vehicle` contains the type of vehicle used on this line. This may include the following properties:

  - `name` contains the name of the vehicle on this line. eg. **"Subway"**.
  - `type` contains the type of vehicle that runs on this line. See the [Vehicle Type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsResponseElements) documentation for a complete list of supported values.
  - `icon` contains the URL for an icon associated with this vehicle type.
  - `local_icon` contains the URL for the icon associated with this vehicle type, based on the local transport signage.

> Note: I think this `short_name` can give you the service number, if
>   you check in your sample request, it will give you a **"short_name" :
>   "500D",** which it is available in your sample screenshot.

Comment: Any work around to get all the buses as we have it on google map. The api provide only the next bus coming to the stop. I tried with >"departure_time" . it returns the same.

Comment: If you check their documentation about their API, you cannot find and ideas to get all the vehicles in the transit mode. So maybe it is not yet supported to that API. Sorry to say, but that is only the limit of my knowledge to that API.

Comment: You can set alternatives=true to get list of upcoming buses